# Read Map of data inside Array in DynamoDb using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I need to scan dynamo db table based on **"labels"**. But I won't be able to read that because my query return null data set.

Here is my sample code

```
itemVal = {"label": "person", "label": "dog"}

response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('tag').contains((itemVal)
)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Here is the sample table data structure. I need to retrieve data based on **"label"**, There will be multiple tag objects for a single id.

```
{
  "id": "http://test.com",
  "tag": [
    {
      "accuracy": 0.9833372306665884,
      "label": "person",
      "rectangle": {
        "height": 144,
        "left": 73,
        "top": 13,
        "width": 121
      }
    },
    {
      "accuracy": 0.9833372306665884,
      "label": "dog",
      "rectangle": {
        "height": 144,
        "left": 73,
        "top": 13,
        "width": 121
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for using internal attributes to filter, so I had to resort to:

- run a scan, updating items (dynamo records) by adding a new attribute ("tag" in your example)
- then, run filtering by that new "tag" attribute
- also, if accesed frequently, may be of interest to add an SGI (secondary index)

Comment: You shoult improve your answer by adding some example code.

Comment: Could you also add a reference to AWS docs where we could learn more about why you can't filter using internal attributes on a query? if you are aware of any